# SIGABRT error - NSUnknownKeyExeption (SetValue:forUndefinedKey;)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, sigabrt

im getting the SIGABRT error each time i build.  Im seeing the reason below:

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key numberEntered.'*

```
-(IBAction)numberEntered:(id)sender
{ 
    NSNumber *day=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%", dayEntry];

    NSLog(@"%@", day);
}
```

I assume its something to do with me trying to pass the wrong value to *day, but i cant see what the issue is (no errors in xCode).

Essentially all i want to do is to retrieve a Numerical value from a textfield and set it do a variable (day) so i can use it in a calculation.  I have added the NSLog in order to ensure im acquiring the correct data from my textfield.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That sounds like a problem in your InterfaceBuilder setup. You will have assigned a UI-element to a type it does not belong to (anymore).

Comment: After searching Stackoverflow i read it could be an issue in IB.  Ive searched around and cant find the issue so far.  Should i be looking in a specific place?

Comment: Check the "Custom Class" property "Class" of the object you have implemented `numberEntered:` for - does it show the Class-Name you are using?

Comment: It's a _UITexfield_.  I have the textfield set to (EditingDidEnd) which calls the numberEntered action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your custom class implementation implementing `numberEntered:` (subclassed `UIView` / `UIViewController` / `UITextFIeld` or whatnot) is actually selected within the InterfaceBuilder under *Custom Class*, *Class*.

For the sake of this example, I am assuming it is a `UIViewController` based class and you call it `MyViewController`. In that sense, you will need to enter that name under the mentioned IB when observing the "File's Owner".

For validating if this actually was your problem, you could add something to your `viewDidLoad` method that prints something into the console. Before being able to do so, you would have to remove that custom method from the event (as that baby would trigger the exception). If that something does not appear when showing the view of that viewController, you know that you have the described issue.

See this:

[image]

Comment: If i follow you correctly, i've changed the xcode specific label to "dayEntry" (or MyTextField for this example).  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have confused you, my bad. See the updated answer.

Comment: I think ive done it right. Check out the image here:db.tt /k9vv1dtP). I dont actually have the placeholders available in my 4.2. version of xCode (at least i cant see it)

Comment: Also, i commented out the action to see if that was causing the problem, and it wasnt.  So im a little stumped.  I need to figure out how to do the step through debugging i think

Comment: Well unfortunately i didnt actually find the root cause of the problem.  However there was certainly some error in how i'd connected up my actions and outlets in Interface builder.  As such i deleted all the connections, and re-connected them.  This has solved the SIGABRT issue finally :D

Answer (score 1):

The other problem is your format string and the fact that you are assigning an `NSString` to an `NSNumber`.

```
NSNumber *day=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%", dayEntry];
```

Try to change it to:

```
NSString *day=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dayEntry];
```

Subtle difference, see if you can spot it.

Comment: Yeah i think i got the difference ;)  It still throws up the SIGABRT issue though.  When should you use NSnumber and when should you use NSString?  I have my UITextfield using the numeric keyboard, so it will always be a number.  I will be taking 3 numbers )3 seperate textfields) to create a date. then eventually comparing two dates to get the difference

Answer (score 0):

try this out :

```
NSNumber *day = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[dayEntry intValue]];
```

Comment: Ive just used that line, and im getting _Reciever Type UITextfield for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'intValue'_

Comment: I added .text after the dayEntry which relieved the fatal error.  However the code still does not run without the SIGABRT fault

Comment: Change it towards `NSNumber *day = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[dayEntry.text intValue]];` then. Your dayEntry instance obviously is a UITextField which does not implement the method intValue. It does however implement the property text (which returns an NSString, which can be converted to an integer by using intvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that you actually have registered the method named `numberEntered:` (note the trailing colon) with IB. It's a method different from `numberEntered` (without the trailing colon). The error might be caused by

- the view calling `numberEntered` (instead of `numberEntered:`)
- the runtime trying to resolve the (undefined method) via KVC lookup.

This could be caused by a missing (or wrong) File's Owner resp. Custom Class defined in a `.xib` file for your control (hinted at by Till) or a plain old typo (missing the trailing `:`).